# AVAudioPlayer : Short sound does not play randomly

Tags: avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer.
I have a short sound in my application.
Randomly it does not play , Play API does not return any error,
Volume is also proper that moment. I am not getting what is going wrong.
Interesting thing is If I play some other sound file, It does play properly every time.
Then I did check properties of both the sound files.
The both the sound files have same bit rate, only difference is
The one which does not play randomly has 00.02 duration.
and the one which play properly has 00.00 duration.

Can anybody give me idea to fix this issue?.